# How to use QGraphicsRotation on a QGraphicsItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgis

I have a [QGraphicsItem](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html)(self.rb). I want to rotate this item around a point(self.originPoint) using [QGraphicsRotation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsrotation.html). But when I try to execute the below code, it gives me the error shown below.  Can someone help?

> in canvasMoveEvent
>       self.rb.setTransform(rotationItem) TypeError: QGraphicsItem.setTransform(QTransform, bool combine=False): argument 1
>   has unexpected type 'QGraphicsRotation'
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

**Code:**

```
def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        self.rb = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, True)
        self.originPoint = self.rb.boundingRect().center()
        if self.rb:return                    

def canvasMoveEvent(self,event):
        if not self.rb:return
        currpoint = self.toLayerCoordinates(self.layer,event.pos())
        angle = center.azimuth( currpoint )

        rotationItem = QGraphicsRotation()
        rotationItem.setAngle = angle
        rotationItem.setOrigin = QVector3D(self.originPoint)
        self.rb.setTransform(rotationItem)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QGraphicsItem.setTransform()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransform) function takes a [QTransform](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtransform.html) as its first argument.  What's catching you off guard is that a [QGraphicsRotation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsrotation.html) isn't a QTransform!  It's in a different hierarchy; it inherits from [QGraphicsTransform](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicstransform.html), which inherits from [QObject](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qobject.html).

So you can't pass in a QGraphicsRotation to rotate your QGraphicsItem, counterintuitive as that is.  You'll have to make a QTransform that does what you want, and use that.

Or - and this is probably a lot easier - use the [QGraphicsItem.setRotation()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation) and [QGraphicsItem.setTransformOriginPoint()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint) functions to apply your desired transformation without worrying about creating any transformation objects yourself.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can apply a `QGraphicsTransform` to `QGraphicsItem` via [`.setTransformations`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformations). However it takes a list of transforms, as it is the use case. For simple transformations, it's preferable to use the dedicated methods (i.e. `setRotation` in this case).

Comment: you were right! i was passing the wrong object type..I tried QGraphicsItem.setRotation()+setTransformOriginPoit()..the setTransformOrignPoint() does not have any effect as i see..